# c# how to run a worker thread with events inside a main form with usercontrols

Tags: multithreading, user-controls

The application I drag and drop items onto the main form which contains a tablelayoutpanel which displays custom user controls about the items dragged in.

The usercontols subscribe to data and have events that run in the backround and are interdependent on the surrounding controls in the panel.

I need to create 2 threads, one the main thread that will display the forms, and then another worker thread that will process all the data from the events from the controls.

The events are part of the controls themselves and need to be subscribed separately for each one.

The problem I am having is how can I create the control and put them in the form in one thread, but have the events handled in the other?

What I am trying now is first to create the GUI with the needed controls inserted. Then I start the worker thread which creates a reference array of the table controls and then have this thread subscribe to the events from the controls separately. This should at no point interact with the main form. And the main form would have a timer and periodically update data to the screen.

Examples I have found and have used are threads launching another form or application or simple worker threads which exit after finishing, which I need a stable background thread that works off the existing gui contents, but is not limited by the display?

Thank you.

Comment: I think I succeeded  in making it run multicolored. But I am not sure how to test that I do have a worker thread running.

Comment: I removed the while(true) DoEvents loop at the end of my thread method, but it seems the thread continues. Is that normal or should I leave the while to be sure.   Also, I have control buttons on the main form as well as the controls and they work fine even though I am not using Invoke. I get not exceptions so far, but is it possible that buttons execute in the wrong thread? THanks.

Comment: After more testing, I found that without the while the thread dies. But the application still runs as normal as events are handled in the display thread. But with the while CPU is at 100, but responsive.  Is there a good way to see which thread something is running in, as I would like to know which thread handles the events subscribed to by the worker thread?